# Solver does not find optimal solution when expanding problems

Tags: pyomo, ipopt

I have noticed that when using Pyomo + Ipopt, some optimization dae problems that converge to an optimal solution, when expanded in complexity (e.g. larger distance in a car example) and consequetly in the number of finite elements to keep accuracy, the solver displays:

```
EXIT: Solved To Acceptable Level.
```

instead of the previous "Optimal solution found".

As an example of stated above, I will use a modified code of "ampl car sample" from Pyomo repository.

```
# Ampl Car Example
#
# Shows how to convert a minimize final time optimal control problem
# to a format pyomo.dae can handle by removing the time scaling from
# the ContinuousSet.
#
# min tf
# dxdt = v
# dvdt = a-R*v^2
# x(0)=0; x(tf)=L
# v(0)=0; v(tf)=0
# -3<=a<=1

from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.dae import *

m = ConcreteModel()

m.R = Param(initialize=0.001) #  Friction factor
m.L = Param(initialize=1000000.0) #  Final position

m.tau = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,1)) # Unscaled time
m.time = Var(m.tau) # Scaled time
m.tf = Var()
m.x = Var(m.tau,bounds=(0,m.L+50))
m.v = Var(m.tau,bounds=(0,None))
m.a = Var(m.tau, bounds=(-3.0,1.0),initialize=0)

m.dtime = DerivativeVar(m.time)
m.dx = DerivativeVar(m.x)
m.dv = DerivativeVar(m.v)

m.obj = Objective(expr=m.tf)

def _ode1(m,i):
    if i == 0 :
        return Constraint.Skip
    return m.dx[i] == m.tf * m.v[i]
m.ode1 = Constraint(m.tau, rule=_ode1)

def _ode2(m,i):
    if i == 0 :
        return Constraint.Skip
    return m.dv[i] == m.tf*(m.a[i] - m.R*m.v[i]**2)
m.ode2 = Constraint(m.tau, rule=_ode2)

def _ode3(m,i):
    if i == 0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    return m.dtime[i] == m.tf
m.ode3 = Constraint(m.tau, rule=_ode3)

def _init(m):
    yield m.x[0] == 0
    yield m.x[1] == m.L
    yield m.v[0] == 0
    yield m.v[1] == 0
    yield m.time[0] == 0
m.initcon = ConstraintList(rule=_init)

discretizer = TransformationFactory('dae.finite_difference')
discretizer.apply_to(m,nfe=5000,scheme='BACKWARD')

solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
solver.solve(m,tee=True)

print("final time = %6.2f" %(value(m.tf)))

x = []
v = []
a = []
time=[]

for i in m.tau:
    time.append(value(m.time[i]))
    x.append(value(m.x[i]))
    v.append(value(m.v[i]))
    a.append(value(m.a[i]))
  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(131)
plt.plot(time,x,label='x')
plt.title('location')
plt.xlabel('time')

plt.subplot(132)
plt.plot(time,v,label='v')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.title('velocity')

plt.subplot(133)
plt.plot(time,a,label='a')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.title('acceleration')

plt.show()
```

NOTE: The original source code can be colsulted here to compare with mine modified: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/main/examples/dae/car_example.py

Is there anything I can do about this? May I lower the ipopt tolerance so it keeps finding for an optimal solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the heuristic that makes Ipopt stop with an "acceptable" solution by setting option acceptable_iter to 0. See https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OPTIONS.html#OPT_Termination for all options that determine termination of Ipopt.